# $request is null for production environment

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony based environment which in my locale `$request->get('example');`, it returns the corresponding value, but in the production environment it returns a null value.
In fact, if I try to see the value of `$_REQUEST`, `$_GET['example']`... I get null in the same way. As if at some point the content of `$_REQUEST` were removed.

In the controller I add `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`.
If I do it in a php file "outside" of Symfony, in pure php, it works fine.
My question is if for the production environment I have to make any changes to be able to see the value of the parameters that I receive in the request.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: it was a problem with the nginx configuration in production environment.

In production, the location was not `try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;`.
Updating that line was solved.